# R stitch in knitr gets confused by comments that look like chunk labels

Tags: r, knitr

I'm using the stitch function in the knitr package in R to create html files of R code for examples for my students.

> I have several hundred R scripts and am automating the process to create the html pages.

However, if my R script contains comment lines such as

> ##------     Example ------

then the stitch function `thinks` this is the label for a code chunk and often drops other parts of my script.

Is there a way to `turn off` **chunking** in the `stitch()` function to pass ALL code `as is`?
I've looked at the internal code for `stitch()` and `read_chunk()` and can't seem to see how it knows when    `## ----- Example -----` is a chunk label.

Here is minimal working example: R 3.0.1; knitr 1.4.1

```
# Test out problem with stitch in knitr

my.code <- "# This a sample of R code
x <- 1:10
print(x)
plot(x,x)

## ---------------- Example  -----
# Notice that only this part of the code appears in the html file.
x <- 10:30
print(x)
plot(x,x)

NULL
"

writeLines(my.code, con='R.code')

library(knitr)
stitch("R.code", system.file("misc", "knitr-template.Rhtml", package = "knitr"))
```

Answer (score 5):

That is a new feature [introduced](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md) in knitr 1.3: `# ----` will be treated as the marker for chunk headers when using `read_chunk()`.

If you do not want this feature, you can use less than 4 dashes after `#`, e.g.

```
## --- Example ----
## -- Example ----
## Example ----
```

I assume you have comments like this for the sake of RStudio code sections, which requires at least four dashes in the end of the section headings.

Then you need the development version [knitr v1.4.6 on Github](https://github.com/yihui/knitr) to completely fix this issue.

Comment: Hmm... I wasn't aware of this new feature... The comments are just legacy code (predates Rstudio!) that served to delineate sections of code in my examples. In my example above, there are more than 4 dashes and it still picks it up as a chunk label. THanks for fixing this in the 1.4.6 release. Carl.

Answer (score 2):

A possible work around is to preprocess your files and change the characters so that `stitch` does not try to interpret those lines:

The following code:

```
require(gsubfn)

tmp <- readLines('example1.R')

gsubfn("(-+)( *Example *)(-+)", function(one,two,three) {
    paste0( paste( rep('=', nchar(one)), collapse='' ),
        two,
        paste( rep('=', nchar(three)), collapse='' ) ) },
    tmp)

writeLines(tmp, 'example1.R')
```

will read in the file "example1.R" and replace any instance of multiple "-" followed by "Example" followed by more "-" (with optional spaces before and after Example) with "=" in place of "-" (same number) and write the result back to the same file.  You can change the regular expression to capture different comments or change the function to replace with a different character.  You could save to a different file name if you don't want to overwrite the original (probably safer).  And you could wrap all of the above in a function and loop through all the files in a folder to modify all of them.  Running `stitch` on the result should then leave the comments alone.